# Powershell script to remove all permissions from a registry key

Tags: windows, powershell, security, registry

There has been a recent vulnerability discovered in Windows 7/Server 2008 that leverages overly generous permissions on a couple of registry keys.

The workaround is apparently to create the key in question and revoke permissions for "users" on that key.

The command, using subinacl is:

```
subinacl.exe /subkeyreg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Performance /revoke=Users
```

Primary Objective:
I'd like to be able to run this in pure powershell (for SCCM baseline configuration setting) and as such, I need to change the ACL on that key to "/revoke" "users" without needing subinacl.

Secondary Objective:
"Users" is a language specific term... is there a SID equivalent that could be used instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Close voters are wrong, this is a great example of how to ask a programming question about computer administration tasks.  OP has already determined what tasks need to be performed and described how it can be done manually / using existing tools.  And asks how to automate it with a specific scripting platform.  That is **clearly** a programming question.

Comment: Now, it may possibly be too broad because it asks for doing the entire task instead of helping with one narrow problem.  But the close votes cast with a reason of "off-topic: questions about general purpose computing software and hardware" are incorrect.

Comment: @BenVoigt - it's possible that it was being downvoted because of my lack of showing research.  I had found https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-change-registry-permissions-with-powershell but I couldn't see how to trim out parts of an acl from it, only how to add and get... I certainly wouldn't have found 'PurgeAccessRules' or know to look for it.

Answer (score 2):

The two big things needed are to disable inheritance using [SetAccessRuleProtection][1] on the key and to use the call to [PurgeAccessRules][2] to remove all rules related to a user object.  The documentation doesn’t reference powershell, so the methods are hard to search for.

The solution ends up as follows:

```
$Usersid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier 'S-1-5-32-545'
$Everyonesid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier 'S-1-1-0'
$user = $Usersid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
$everyone = $Everyonesid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
$DNSCacheBasePath='hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\services\dnscache'
$RpcEptMapperBasePath='hklm:\system\currentcontrolset\services\rpceptmapper'
$aclpaths=($DNSCacheBasePath,$RpcEptMapperBasePath)
# get the current acl
foreach ($aclpath in $aclpaths)
{
    $perfpath=$aclpath+'\Performance'
    if (!(Test-Path $perfpath))
    {
        New-Item $aclpath -Name Performance |Out-Null
    }
    $acl = get-acl $perfpath
    # disable permission inheritance and copy existing permissions to explicit permissions on parent Key
    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true)
    # write the changes back to the reg key
    $acl | Set-Acl -Path $perfpath
    # get the new (inheritance disabled) permission structure
    $acl = get-acl $perfpath
    # remove any rule that applies to Users
    $acl.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$user)
    $acl.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$everyone)
    # write the changes 
    $acl | Set-Acl -Path $perfpath
    # fix Parent ACL
    $acl = get-acl $aclpath
    # Enale Inheritance on the parent key
    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($false,$true)
    # Ensure that Users have ReadKey privs on the parent
    $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule($user,[System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]::ReadKey,"Allow")
    $acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
    # write the changes 
    $acl | Set-Acl -Path $aclpath
}
```

Comment: The only improvement I would suggest is to move the Test-Path and New-Item stuff into the loop.  Having those long registry paths each repeated 3 times is really ugly and a maintenance headache.

Comment: @BenVoigt - noted... cleaned up in my final version that I have - should I update my answer?

Comment: Yes, future reader who find this question will appreciate seeing the best version of the code.  Sometimes error handling gets abbreviated in an answer in order to make the important steps clearer, but pretty much any change that makes the code more readable and better organized would be desired in the answer as well.